# Automator workflow runs forever

Tags: macos, automator

I have run into a problem with automator: I have a workflow that does image processing (it converts color images to gray). I am able to invoke the workflow from the terminal and it works fine. The command is:
   automator -i infile.jpg imageconversion.workflow

However, I am facing a problem when I try to integrate this workflow in a webapp, build in Django and deployed with mod_wsgi on Apache. The workflow gets invoked (I can see this from the webapp logs), but it runs forever, and eventually apache will kill the child process after several minutes.

I am running OS X 10.9

Has anybody encountered a similar issue?

Thanks,
Gerald

Answer (score 2):

## Limitations of Automator

Your Automator workflow may require access to the WindowServer to work. Automator is designed to be run within an active user session, and not from a shell session.

The Apache user launching your Automator workflow is running without access to the WindowServer and this will likely limit which actions you can use.

### ImageMagik

Consider using an image processing tool designed for command line use, such as [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org). Take a look at the [-greyscale](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#grayscale) option for your conversion:

```
convert in.png -grayscale Rec709Luminance out.png
```